# Discord Python Bot With Different Source Files

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm having trouble with my Discord Bot in Python.

The code for it became just too much for having a good overview, so I wanted to split it up into different source-files.

(Main-File)

```
...        
import second_file
if message.content.lower().startswith("!Hi"):
    second_file.hello()
```

(Second-File)

```
...
from __main__ import client
def hello():
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Hiii <3!")
```

The error I am getting is `name "client" is not defined`.

What should I do?
Thanks :)

Comment: If my answer worked please mark it as correct so anyone in the future can fix their issue.

Comment: You should really just look into creating Cogs. Using Cogs will make your life so much easier. EDIT: You would also need to look in commands.ext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `from __main__ import client` with `from main import client` assuming your main python file is called `main.py`.

You need to do this because python wants just the file name when importing another script. I would also recommend changing your main file name to something else as `__main__` in python is reserved for other things.

Comment: Sadly that didn't fix it...
Now it just says:
"Invalid syntax" at client.send_message(message.channel, "Hiii <3!")"
And the pointer is by the "t" of client.

Comment: It was named " __ main __ " because I heared that Python uses " __ main __ " for the calling script

Comment: Rename the file to something else and try doing it again

Comment: Still "invalid syntax". And the pointer points again to the "t" of client, although I think it is referenced to the "." after the client.

Comment: Do you have a function called client in your main file?

Comment: Not directly a function but : "client = discord.Client()", which is an object... I think?

Comment: No. Try maybe creating a function called client and return discord.Client() to it. I think that may work.

Comment: Or try importing just the file not using from and do main.client. Not sure if that will work. I think youu need a function

Comment: It needs to be a function.

Comment: I tried it like a function:

    def client():
        client = discord.Client()
        return client

Comment: The only problem is that the second_file does not execute its code, because it doesn't recognize the client as such. And therefor it doesn't know  what to do with "send_message.()"

Comment: Why dont you combine the files.

Comment: I used those as a "test" for splitting up my 700 codeline bot

Comment: Of course it will, but this is not what this thread is about. It is about splitting up this 700 codeline file into differen ones to get a better overview. I just ran into this issue while trying to do so.

Comment: So far you are right... no matter what I do it doesn't work... I've approved your answer :)

Comment: This might sound like a hackjob, but just pass client around. In second file, try `hello(client):` and in the main file, do `second_file.hello(client)`. Also, you'll probably have to pass message in too so that it can use `message.channel`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
The problem is that you are using `await` outside of an `async` function.
I don't know the real reason why that throws the error though.
You also don't necessarily need to import `client` from `__main__`.
You can use

```
await __main__.client.send_message(__main__.message.channel, 'Hello')`
```

just fine.
But try this code:

```
(Main-file)
import second_file
if message.content.lower().startswith('!hi'):
    second_file.hello()

(Second-file)

async def hello():
    await __main__.client.send_message(__main__.message.channel, 'Hello!')
```

Sorry if i have any grammatical, or spelling mistakes. English isn't my native language (unfortunataly D: )
Hope this helps you as well